# Group Bar chart in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, reporting, dashboard, powerbi-desktop

I have a dashboard in power BI that i want to group the countries by their continent name using bar chart
currently when I do it i have the below

[image]

Expected output

[image]

Any idea on how i can achieve this?

this is my day

```
Continet              Country         TotalSales
Africa                Ghana           7612491.751
Africa                Nigeria         14124361.42
Africa                South Africa    5112305.914
Asia                  China           17817372.96
Asia                  India           7641389.641
Australia/Oceania     Australia       12740363.52
Europe                France          15415410.76
Europe                Germany         12750071.97
Europe                Turkey          6382936.304
Europe                United Kingdom  23096905.81
North America         Canada          8812713.914
North America         United States   11517603.12
South America         Brazil          10218528.38
```

Comment: Is your question about the visual or about the table setup?

Comment: @Aldert the visual display, to separate countries and put in continent as shown in the second picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put both `Continet` and `Country` in the Axis box and drill down but for some reason, Power BI only lets you turn off Concatenate labels on a horizontal bar chart.

[image: Horizonal Chart]